# How to open multiple windows/instances of double commander

Tags: double-commander

I'm using Double Commander on Windows. I'd like to open a new Window, but the [Ctrl] + [N] keyboard shortcut doesn't seem to do anything.

I've looked in the keyboard shortcuts config, but can't seem to find a command to do the thing I want. `cm_Open` opens the file in question rather than a new window.

Strictly speaking I don't *need* a new window, but the Window analogy explains my needs well: I'm looking for a way to keep the current state of my panes (in particular the paths in each of the panes, which is something I'm currently interested in coming back to, but not something worth saving to come back to regularly), and open up a separate set of 2 panes that can be navigated to new locations without affecting the original set, and while leaving the original panes quickly and obviously accessible until I'm done with them and choose to 'close' (discard) them.

Each set of panes should be quickly visible and accessible (on a par with [Alt] + [Tab]), the panes should be 'linked' (I shouldn't have to take one action to set one pane and then another action to set the other pane) and there should be no particular setup (beyond perhaps selecting a path to show) involved in creating a new 'Window' (pair of locations) - typically the new window would .

Is there a way to do what I'm after?